# Scheduling on shared hosting

Tags: scheduling, shared-hosting

I'm in the process of writing a scheduling application on a shared hosting server. So far it doesn't look like my scheduling will have to be any more granular than daily, but that could change later. Ideally, I'll want to use a Windows host so I write my application in .NET but I'm open to using a PHP+*nix host.

In a shared hosting environment (read: cheap) how can I write an application where notifications can occur on a scheduled basis?

Comment: Take a look at this list of cron services, they exists specifically to help with cron on shared hosting accounts: http://www.onlinecronservices.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a *nix system, you're going to want to use `cron`. An example of its use, starting a process every day at 3:20 AM:

```
echo "20 3 * * * /path/to/run-my-job.sh" | crontab
```

**edit**: To answer the question asked in a comment on another response, it depends on the shared host; [many](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/index.php/Crontab) [of](http://he.net/hosting.html) [them](http://help.godaddy.com/topic/67/article/3549) allow you to run cron jobs.

Comment: I never piped anything to crontab in my life till just now +1

Answer (score 4):

Are you wanting something like a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)?

Steve

Comment: Do shared hosts tend to allow you to do your own cron jobs?

Comment: Any good host allows you to run cron jobs, yes.  My host allows SSH on shared accounts.

Comment: You can also use a tool like SetCronJob (http://www.setcronjob.com/) if your host doesn't support cron jobs.

Comment: Setcronjob.com was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!